# Referencing a PROCESS in Emacs (ESS R)

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I am trying to run a command from Emacs using ESS, to send code to the R buffer (though I have stumbled onto this problem in python as well).

I can't figure out though how to use:

`(ess-send-string PROCESS STRING)`

I do not understand how I can, while calling this function from the script buffer, send a string to the associated *R* buffer.

I have tried using `comint` and `process-send-string`, but I guess I do not understand how to send a process. A buffer name did not do it, what will?

Example:

```
(defun create-rtags () 
  (interactive)
  (ess-send-string PROCESS "rtags(ofile=paste0(getwd(), \"TAGS\"))")
```

Comment: May be I don't get your question but did you try one of `C-c C-n` (Eval-line and step), `C-c C-j` (Eval line), `C-c C-r` (eval region) or `C-c C-b` (eval buffer) in a ESS-buffer

Comment: You're evaluating text from a buffer, I am trying to evaluate a string as mentioned in a command (without text being in an R buffer, but in an `.el` file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `get-process` to have the right process or `ess-get-process` if you use the latest of ESS version on github.

```
(ess-send-string (get-process "R") "a <- 1:10;a")
```

Result in

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

So for your function, something like this should work

```
(defun create-rtags () 
  (interactive)
  (ess-send-string (get-process "R") "rtags(ofile = file.path(getwd(), \"TAGS\"))"))
```

Comment: Yea, the `(get-process ...)` is the thing! What is the string "R" here though, a buffer name?

Comment: @Dualinity This part is quite confusing in the emacs help file they wrote *..In these functions, the process argument can be a process or the name of a process, or a buffer or buffer name (which stands for a process via get-buffer-process)..* So it was a lot a trial and error before getting it

Comment: Also, I find the first part not to be really relevant... The latter is the answer, I'll mark it such. Still curious to why `"R"`: I believe I once tried the `(get-process "*R*")`, thinking it needs the buffer-name. What will happen when you create a second process, how to access that one?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still confused: `(get-proces "R")` works, even though the buffer-name equals `"*R*"`

Comment: @Dualinity I removed the first part and like you I think is just the buffer name but without the stars...http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Input-to-Processes.html

Comment: The name of a process is separate from the name of its buffer, and can be seen through `M-x list-processes`.

Comment: @Dualinity there's something to improve here because is still not accepted ?

Comment: @legoscia Thank you for this command, very useful and now it's clear

Answer (score 1):

To add to @dickoa answer. ESS handles multiple processes and they are all listed in `ess-proces-name-list`. "R" is the name of the first open R process. In ESS buffers there is local vairable `ess-local-process-name` which links the buffer with the process.

FWIW, <kbd>C-c C-e C-t</kbd> is bound to `ess-build-tags-for-directory` in ESS. It is smart enough to send rtags command from R buffers and a regexp etag request (based on current imenu regexp) from other buffers.